# How to fix: "deno error: Cannot resolve module 'x'"

Tags: deno

I've got an error like so:

```
error: Cannot resolve module "<path>/src/routes" from "<path>/src/index.ts"
Imported from "file:///F:/Development/k8demo/api-deno/src/index.ts:2"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem was that Deno requires a `.ts` extension for imports unlike node.
Fix by adding `.ts` to the import.

Comment: Deno requires explicit extensions. It is designed this way such that it can tell differences between different file types (e.g. `main.ts` vs `main.js`), and complies with how browser actual resolve imports.

Comment: I have the same problem. When I add .ts to the end of an import, my VS Code shows this error: "An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing './main' instead. ts(2691)".
Any solutions?

Comment: @IceRevenge I installed deno plugglin for vs code and enabled it in the settings.json. With that, I could add .ts to the import and it worked as intended.

Comment: Having .ts on the import does not fix this issue for me.